# If you exceed For How Long the Geocoding API after exceeding the limit?

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoder

We recently encountered a problem that cause us to exceed the `Geocoding API` daily limit, so we can use it anymore on our website.

Does anyone know for how long the service is blocked in this case ?

The documentation says :

> "If you exceed the 24-hour limit or otherwise abuse the service, the
>   Geocoding API may stop working for you temporarily. If you continue to
>   exceed this limit, your access to the Geocoding API may be blocked."

So

> Question #1 : How long is "temporarily"...
>   
> Question #2 : if our
>   access to the Geocoding API is blocked (IP Blacklist), is there a way
>   to be "unblocked" ? Who shall web contact ?

Thank you very mutch for your answers :-)

Chris

Comment: Have you checked if the service starts working after the 24-hour period is over? Someone knows if the google-geocoding-api tag is actually in use?

Comment: Why in the world would they put a limit on how many lookups you can do in a day?  If they charge based on usage aren't they incentivized to let you use it as much as possible?